No guarda registros en PostgreSQL desde aplicación de Python
estoy intentando realizar una aplicación de escritorio con Python y conectarla a una base de datos PostgreSQL para el registro de variables simples de texto, si bien el CRUD corre perfectamente en la terminal de Visual Studio Code, al momento de ingresar los datos desde la aplicación de tkinter y hacer clic en guardar, se limpia la ventana de las entradas pero el registro no se realizar de forma exitosa visto que no se guardan los datos en la base de datos ni se reflejan en la aplicación, es como si simplemente se desaparecieran o se borraran en vez de guardarse, he revisado el código en varias oportunidades e incluso la conexión a la base de datos si esta bien, pero ya no se que puedo hacer y por eso acudo a esta comunidad en busca de un apoyo que pudiera ser efectivo en la resolución de esta problemática.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from database import *

class App:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.ventana = master
        self.DibujarLabel()
        self.DibujarEntry()
        self.DibujarBoton()
        self.DibujarLista()
        
               
    def DibujarLabel(self):
        self.lbl_fuente = Label(self.ventana, foreground="white", background="#314252", text="Fuente", font=(8)).place(x=60, y=110)
        self.lbl_fecha = Label(self.ventana, foreground="white", background="#314252", text="Fecha", font=(8)).place(x=60, y=160)
        self.lbl_usuario = Label(self.ventana, foreground="white", background="#314252", text="Usuario", font=(8)).place(x=60, y=210)
        self.lbl_descripcion = Label(self.ventana, foreground="white", background="#314252", text="Descripción", font=(8)).place(x=60, y=260)
        self.lbl_categoria = Label(self.ventana, foreground="white", background="#314252", text="Categoría", font=(8)).place(x=60, y=310)
        self.lbl_elemento = Label(self.ventana, foreground="white", background="#314252", text="Elemento", font=(8)).place(x=60, y=360)
    
    def DibujarEntry(self):
        self.fuente = StringVar()
        self.fecha = StringVar()
        self.usuario = StringVar()
        self.descripcion = StringVar()
        self.categoria = StringVar()
        self.elemento = StringVar()
        self.txt_fuente = Entry(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12), textvariable=self.fuente).place(x=160, y=110)
        self.txt_fecha = Entry(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12), textvariable=self.fecha).place(x=160, y=160)
        self.txt_usuario = Entry(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12), textvariable=self.usuario).place(x=160, y=210)
        self.txt_descripcion = Entry(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12), textvariable=self.descripcion).place(x=160, y=260)
        self.txt_categoria = Entry(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12), textvariable=self.categoria).place(x=160, y=310)
        self.txt_elemento = Entry(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12), textvariable=self.elemento).place(x=160, y=360)
        
    def DibujarBoton(self):
        self.btn_guardar = Button(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12),text="Guardar", relief="flat", background="#0051C8", cursor="hand1", foreground="white", command=lambda: self.guardar()).place(x=750, y=340, width=90)
        self.btn_cancelar = Button(self.ventana, font=('Arial', 12),text="Cancelar", relief="flat", background="red", cursor="hand1", foreground="white").place(x=850, y=340, width=90)
    
    def guardar(self):
        arr = [self.fuente.get(), self.fecha.get(), self.usuario.get(), self.descripcion.get(), self.categoria.get(), self.elemento.get()]
        d = Data()
        d.InsertarEvento(arr)
        self.fuente.set("")
        self.fecha.set("")
        self.usuario.set("")
        self.descripcion.set("")
        self.categoria.set("")
        self.elemento.set("")
        self.LimpiarLista()
        self.DibujarLista()
            
    def LimpiarLista(self):
        self.lista.delete(*self.lista.get_children())    
        
    def DibujarLista(self):
        self.lista = ttk.Treeview(self.ventana, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), show="headings", height="8")
        #estilo
        estilo = ttk.Style()
        estilo.theme_use("clam")
        
        estilo.configure("Treeview.Heading", background="#0051C8", relief="flat", foreground="white")
        self.lista.heading(1, text="Fuente")
        self.lista.heading(2, text="Fecha")
        self.lista.heading(3, text="Usuario")
        self.lista.heading(4, text="Descripción")
        self.lista.heading(5, text="Categoria")
        self.lista.heading(6, text="Elemento")
        self.lista.column(2, anchor=CENTER)
        
        #lista de llenado
        d = Data()
        eventos = d.ConsultarTodo()
        for i in eventos:
            self.lista.insert('', 'end', values=i)        
        self.lista.place(x=380, y=110)
         
root = Tk()
root.title("Base de Datos de Riesgo Reputacional")
root.geometry("1000x400")
root.config(background="#314252")
aplication = App(root)
root.mainloop()

